# How are instructions laid out in memory?

Tags: architecture, cpu, machine-code, instructions

I'm taking an Computer Architecture and Organization class, and we're studying how the instructions are taken from memory and decoded (using an old IAS model as reference). However, I don't quite understand how said instructions would look like in memory.

Let's say I'm making a game, or other program with a large number of instructions, probably even some that would work on multiple threads (although I haven't really studied multi-threading in a structural level yet). **When the program is loaded and starts execution, are all the instructions allocated into a contiguous segment of memory, so that the program counter can always iterate through them by going to the one in the next memory position? Or do modern computers have a way of storing instructions that is wholly different from the IAS?**

To note, however: my understanding of how memory works is still quite primitive to say the least, so I think of memory in a kinda abstracted manner where it's basically a long, long array with every position being a byte or word. Do tell me if this is a wrong way of visualizing it.

Comment: Instructions don't necessarily have to be all positioned one after another in the program image, but they usually are. Instruction have variable size in most architectures, for instance 1..15 bytes in `x86-64`, and CPU needs to fully decode each instruction to find out where the next instruction is.

Comment: huh, but how is it able to do that @vitsoft? does each instruction have some information on where the next one is or should be?

Comment: CPU knows how to do it. Look at some open-source disassembler suitable for your architecture.